# Ajax for id check in jsp only returns same result

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I've been working to check id using ajax in jsp. So when user try to make a new account, they will type id they want to make and ajax will check if there is same id in database or not. If there is, it returns 'n' and in jsp it changed into 'unavailable.' If there is no same id, it returns 'y' and in jsp it changed into 'available.' The problem is it seems like only returns 'n'.

Here is javascript.

```
 $('#email').keyup(function(){
    var str = $(this).val();
    var server = "idcheck";     
    $.post(server, {"email":str}, function(data){
        if(data.ret =='y'){
            $('#valid_check').html("available");
        }else if(data.ret =='n'){
            $('#valid_check').html("unavailable");
        }

        });
    });
```

Here is join.jsp.

```
<label id="valid_check">check if you can use id</label>
<input id="email" name="email" type="email" class="form-style-join" placeholder="ex> mymail477@gmail.com" />
```

Here is controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/idcheck", method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST })
public @ResponseBody HashMap<String,String> idCheck(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response){
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

    String mem_id = request.getParameter("mem_id"); 
    int ret= memberMapper.memberIDCheck(mem_id);

    HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();


    if(ret == 1){
        map.put("ret", "y");

    }else if( ret != 1){
        map.put("ret", "n");
    }

    System.out.println(map);
    return map;
}
```

Here is Mapper.

```
@Select("SELECT count(*) AS cnt FROM `member` WHERE mem_id=#{mem_id}")
public int memberIDCheck(String mem_id);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to ensure that you get the input field value in your spring controller method. So here you are sending a parameter {"email":str} but in controller you are looking for "mem_id".

Try this code :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/idcheck", method =  RequestMethod.POST })
public @ResponseBody HashMap<String,String> idCheck(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, @RequestBody String email){
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
response.setContentType("application/json");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

String mem_id = email; 
int ret= memberMapper.memberIDCheck(mem_id);

HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();


if(ret == 1){
    map.put("ret", "y");

}else if( ret != 1){
    map.put("ret", "n");
}

System.out.println(map);
return map;
```

}

Here I added a @RequestBody. So that the data "email" that is bound in ajax request could be mapped to the method parameter email.